# Proof that some sets of disk algebra are open

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $D = \{z \in \mathbb C: |z|< 1\}$ and let $A(D)$ be the disk algebra, i.e the Banach algebra of functions $D \to \mathbb C$ that are analytic in $D$ and continuous in $\overline D$ with the supremum norm in D, denoted by $\| \cdot \|$. Define
$$ S_{m,n} = \left \{ f \in A(D): \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\|f^{(k)}\|}{k!} > n\right \} \text{ and } S_n = \bigcup_{m \geq n} S_{m,n}. $$

I'm trying to proof that each $S_n$ is an open subset of $A(D)$.

My attempt: Given $n \geq 1$ and $f \in S_n, \, \exists m\geq n, \, f \in S_{m,n}$, i.e
$$ \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\|f^{(k)}\|}{k!} > n. $$

So, I have to find a $\delta > 0$ such that if $g \in A(D)$ and $\|f-g\| < \delta$, $g \in S_n$, i.e $g \in S_{M,n}$ for some $M\geq n$.

$$ \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{\|g^{(k)}\|}{k!} \geq  \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{\|f^{(k)}\|}{k!} - \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{\|g^{(k)} - f^{(k)}\|}{k!} > n - \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{\|g^{(k)} - f^{(k)}\|}{k!}.  $$

However, I don't see how I can conclude the proof.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

First, there's a typo in your definition of $S_{m,n}$: surely the index on the sum should be $k$, not $n$. And the notation $\|f^{(k)}\|$ seems unfortunate, since $f^{(k)}$ need not be an element of the disk algebra. If we write the definition like so

$$S_{m,n} = \left \{ f \in A(D): \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\sup_{|z|<1}|f^{(k)}(z)|}{k!} > n\right \}$$

then it's easy to show that $S_{m,n}$ is open. Two hints:

(i) $f\in S_{m,n}$ if and only if $f\in A(D)$ and there exist $z_0,\dots,z_m\in D$ with $$\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{|f^{(k)}(z_k)|}{k!}>n,$$

(ii) If $f\in A(D)$ and $z\in D$ then $$|f^{(k)}(z)|\le\frac{k!||f||}{(1-|z|)^k}$$(apply "Cauchy's Estimates" in $D(z,1-|z|)$).

Comment: How can I proof that exists such $z_0,\cdots, z_m \in D$ as above? I've been trying here. But I'm stuck, since I can't proof that exists $z_k$ such that $|f^{(k)}(z_k)| = \sup_{z \leq 1} |f^{(k)}(z)|$

Comment: @user242964 It's not necessarily true that there exists $z_k$ with $|f^{(k)}(z_k)|=\sup|f^{(k)}|$. All you need here is that if $S\subset\Bbb R$ and $\sup S>a$ then there exists $x\in S$ with $x>a$. (Proof: Since $\sup S$ is the least upper bound of $S$, it follows that $a$ is not an upper bound for $S$.)

Comment: @user242964 Btw there's no such thing as $\sup_{|z|\le1}|f^{(k)}(z)|$.

Comment: I'm stuck in this problem in a while. I reposted it with some changes. If you could take a look in what I've been doing

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2959843/open-set-of-analytic-functions